# SQL CE Filter by Effective Date using SubSelect

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, subquery

I am trying to filter by effective date in my SQLce (Version 3.5) database in C#.  Here is my Query:

```
SELECT        FirstName, LastName, HomeID, ConditionID, ADate, OwnerID
FROM            Sys_HomeOwner
WHERE        (ADate =
                             (SELECT        MAX(ADate) AS Expr1
                               FROM            Sys_HomeOwner AS Sys_HomeOwner_1))
```

Error returned is:

> There was an error parsing the query. 
>   (token line number=1, token line
>   offset=118, token in error=SELECT]

I have been doing some querying and it seems it is possible to do subselects in SQLCE.  If i pull out the subselect it runs OK for the table as a whole anyway pulling the max date.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You mention getting each rows maximum, I think you need to use a `GROUP BY` for that.

How about:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, NameID, ConditionID, ADate, OwnerID
FROM Sys_HomeOwner h
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ADate) AS maxdate, HomeID
                 FROM Sys_HomeOwner
                 GROUP BY HomeID) AS effectiveDates
     ON h.HomeID = effectiveDates.HomeID
WHERE h.ADate = effectiveDates.maxdate
```

Assuming you want to get the latest dates for each HomeID

Comment: You are correct that I need latest dates based on homeid.  Here is the error:  The derived table sql construct or statement is not supported.  The column name cannot be resolved to a table.  specify the table to which the column belongs.  [name of ambiguous column = HomeID].  I am going to do some looking on this error.  I like your approach.  I hadn't though of that.

Comment: You just need to prefix HomeID with either the table alias or name.  for example Sys_HomeOwner.HomeID or Expr1.HomeID

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am preceding them with the alias and am now getting:  The Derived Table SQL contruct or statement is not supported

Comment: @bline22 Perhaps you need to update your question with the latest query you have.  Depending on the CE edition (Not sure about the latest) but the engine does not support sub queries in SELECT or WHERE

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, LastName, HomeID, ConditionID, ADate, OwnerID 
FROM Sys_HomeOwner 
ORDER BY ADate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Here is the error i get when i try it:Top Clause support not available in SQLCE

Comment: Additional thought, wont the top clause only return the first row of data?  I need to get each row's' max effective dated row so multiple rows will be returned.  Not sure Top would work here anyway?

Comment: TOP is supported in version 3.5 and later (not in 3.0 though)